# Вычисление VWAP, заканчивается ОЗУ, слишком долго выполняется код

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Подскажите в чём проблема: вычисляю VWAP на 1 минуту. Выполняется около получаса, после чего заканчивается ОЗУ (16ГБ). Как с этим бороться?

Код:

```
def vwap(data):
    return np.sum(data['Volume']*data['Price']) / np.sum(data['Volume'])

df_vwap = df.resample('T').apply(vwap)
```

Информация по датасету:

```
DatetimeIndex: 50129623 entries, 2011-09-13 13:53:44 to 2021-04-08 10:17:12
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Dtype  
---  ------  -----  
 0   Price   float64
 1   Volume  float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 1.1 GB
```

Пример:

```
                    Cost    Volume
Timestamp       
2011-09-13 13:53:44 5.83    3.000000
2011-09-13 13:53:49 5.90    1.000000
2011-09-13 13:53:54 6.00    20.000000
2011-09-13 14:32:53 5.95    12.452100
2011-09-13 14:35:04 5.88    7.458000
... ... ...
2021-04-08 10:17:04 56461.22    0.002285
2021-04-08 10:17:05 56461.21    0.000796
2021-04-08 10:17:07 56452.21    0.012384
2021-04-08 10:17:12 56462.07    0.221461
2021-04-08 10:17:12 56462.08    0.003029
50129623 rows × 2 columns
```

Датасет взят с биржи bitstamp.
Изначально время идёт в unix, я его преобразовал в datetime и сделал индексом, но думаю это не важно.

Кстати, замерил время для первой тысячи строк, выполнялось 2 минуты. То есть, если бы не ОЗУ, то это заняло бы больше месяца с такой скоростью?

При этом необходимо отметить, что к примеру resample('T') и взятие среднего выполняется относительно быстро.

```
%%time
df.resample('T').mean()
>> CPU times: user 9.33 s, sys: 99.6 ms, total: 9.43 s
>> Wall time: 9.45 s
```

Также проверил .apply():

```
df.resample('T').apply(np.mean)
>> CPU times: user 9.3 s, sys: 41.5 ms, total: 9.34 s
>> Wall time: 9.38 s
```

Но если добавить mean() в свою функцию и передать в apply, то выполняется долго > 5 минут (дальше остановил). Ещё попробовал .transform, но это тоже не принесло положительных результатов.
При каждом тесте перезапускал ядро, так что это время выполнения с 0.

Насколько это эффективный код и как его оптимизировать?

Comment: Советы у меня есть, но сначала нужно прояснить ситуацию: 1) Покажите пример ваших данных. 2) Данные у вас по одной бумаге или нескольким? 3) Данные за один день или нет?

Comment: 1) Вот пример: (1 - datetime, 2 - price, 3 - volume)
2011-09-13 13:53:44 5.83 3.0000
2011-09-13 13:53:49 5.90 1.0000
2011-09-13 13:53:54 6.00 20.0000


info:
DatetimeIndex: 50129623 entries, 2011-09-13 13:53:44 to 2021-04-08 10:17:12
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Dtype  
---  ------  -----  
 0   Price   float64
 1   Volume  float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 1.1 GB

2) Да, по одной, BTC данные с Bitstamp.
3) Данные за 10 лет.
Комментарии не позволяют сохранить структуру сообщения, надеюсь понятно будет.

Comment: Так вы отредактируйте вопрос, в него добавьте пример данных. Вам надо в любом случае будет делать не через apply, а "векторно", только сообразить как правильно сгруппировать данные. С ходу не соображу но должно быть несложно

Comment: С ходу могу предложить перевести данные в формат float32, а то и float16 для экономии памяти. И заранее посчитать дополнительную колонку volume * price и использовать её в расчёте. Возможно, это поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я ничего не напутал, то как-то так можно всё подсократить. Считается практически моментально (в Google Colab - примерно 3 секунды для ваших 50 млн. записей):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# подготовка искусственных данных
n = 50_000_000
dt1 = '2011-01-01'
dt2 = '2021-01-01'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price': np.random.rand(n), 'Volume': np.random.rand(n) * 100}, index=pd.date_range(dt1, dt2, n))

# вычисления
df['PriceVolume'] = df.Price * df.Volume
df_vwap = df.resample('T').sum()
df_vwap['VWAP'] = df_vwap.PriceVolume / df_vwap.Volume
df_vwap
```

Вывод:

```
                       Price        Volume PriceVolume      VWAP
2011-01-01 00:00:00 5.192511    496.556623  254.670320  0.512873
2011-01-01 00:01:00 7.141745    309.744509  223.159254  0.720462
2011-01-01 00:02:00 4.360215    397.390823  201.644752  0.507422
2011-01-01 00:03:00 5.144041    377.992786  206.868020  0.547280
2011-01-01 00:04:00 3.872896    528.529505  298.234094  0.564271
... ... ... ... ...
2020-12-31 23:56:00 5.252985    347.602048  154.309640  0.443926
2020-12-31 23:57:00 4.999989    537.402149  282.032086  0.524806
2020-12-31 23:58:00 6.908802    520.533699  327.953591  0.630033
2020-12-31 23:59:00 5.202762    526.833848  304.883723  0.578709
2021-01-01 00:00:00 0.590265    24.786377   14.630522   0.590265
5260321 rows × 4 columns
```

То есть я заранее посчитал `data['Volume']*data['Price']` сразу для всех записей, ну и вообще что там в `apply` происходит я не очень разобрался, но вам же там нужна сумма, так что спокойно можно использовать аггрегатор `.sum`, а потом опять же "векторно" поделить полученные колонки с суммами сразу для всего датафрейма. Так всё вычисляется гораздо быстрее.

Comment: Спасибо! Это именно то, что я пытался сделать. Зациклился на применении функции. Опыта пока немного, но теперь точно знаю, что к apply прибегать только в крайнем случае, сначала векторизация.  Получилось в точности как я хотел, теперь смогу добавлять в датасет актуальные данные, ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: @Huginn Да, обычно почти всё можно решить векторизацией, иногда ещё с `groupby` и аггрегацией. А всякие `iterrows` и `apply` - только в крайнем случае, ага.